# Create command that displays input exactly

Tags: macros, verbatim

I want to create a command whose argument is used within a `\label{}` command. I also want a boolean switch that turns on/off the display of this label for editing purposes. Here is pseudo-code for what I'd like to do:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{foocount}\label{#1}%
  ... do other things ... %
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{showlabel}}%
  {DISPLAY #1}%
  {}%
  }
```

The problem is in the `DISPLAY #1` part. I want to display the label no matter what the label contains. For instance, many of my labels have the form "`ex:function_continuous_everywhere`" but the underscores causes math-mode errors. Using variations of `\verbatim` has its own set of issues.

Is there a slick way of doing this? I know I could change all my labels, but I'd rather not.

Comment: You can look at the package `showkeys` that shows labels automatically.

Comment: @egreg: Very nice. That does the trick, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}` for the `DISPLAY #1` part. This will convert the argument into text (e.g. the `_` are turned into normal characters and are no longer math shift sequences) and typesets it in teletyper font.

Note that `\detokenize` is an e-TeX primitive, so very old or outdated LaTeX distributions won't have it.

Comment: Never heard of \detokenize before. Perfect; thanks.